# How can I get the focussed Point of a Camera?

Tags: 3d, camera, geometry

I'm trying to calculate the point, which the Camera is looking on.
The Camera has a Rotation around the X-axis and the Y-axis.
I want to calculate the point, which is 1cm away and on the same line, as my Camera.

I know how to calculate something like this in 2D but when I get to 3D, I get in trouble.

This is for 2D (only x and z axis):

```
float c = 1f;
float a = c * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotationY));
float b = (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotationY)) * c);
newPosition.z -= a;
newPosition.x += b;
```

But with 3D I need help.

I hope somebody here knows the awnser.

Comment: This is not a OpenGL problem (OpenGL just deals with drawing stuff), but a 3D geometry problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to take the inverse of the camera's view matrix, and then transform a point 1cm in front of the camera by this matrix.

If your camera first is rotated by X degrees around the X axis, and Y degrees around the y axis, then in pseudocode it might look like this:

```
Matrix4D camMM = Matrix4D.Identity(); //camera model matrix
camMM.Rotate(X, 1, 0, 0);
camMM.Rotate(Y, 0, 1, 0);
Vector4D focusPoint = camMM * vector4D(-1cm, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Thx for the Reply, but is there any Chance to do it easier? Because I don't have a big knowledge about OpenGl and the Matrix. Can I do it like my code in my first post?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to replace matrix math with a lot of trigonometry (I don't have the answer off top of my head), but if you plan to work in 3D I'll strongly suggest that you start getting familiar with 3d matrix math. It's the foundation for pretty much everything you can do with OpenGL. It can seem strange and difficult at first, but matrix math and linear algebra is probably one of the most important things you can learn if you're going to be working with computer graphics. @user1432679

Comment: @user1432679: A transformation matrix in computer graphics is effectivly just another coordinate system relative to another one. Doing this using matrices is the most straightforward way. If you don't know them, well, learn them.